# unicode to zh-cN

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

```
NSArray *array=[contentOfResponseDataInJsonValue JSONValue];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

prints:

```
(
    (
        (
        "\U515c\U639b\U8e55",
        AABENRAA,
        " o b\U8c46n lu\U8eab"
        )
    ),
    (
    ),
    en
)
```

but

```
if (array==nil) {
    return returnStr=@"";
}else {
    returnStr=[[[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] ;
}
NSLog(@"result is %@",returnStr);
```

show :兜掛蹕

`\U515c\U639b\U8e55`     to       兜掛蹕      why ,why!

please help me !!!    thanks!

Comment: The two sections of Chinese render identically for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *contentOfResponseDataInJsonValue = 
   [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:encoder=-2147483646 error:&error];
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is this? You are using the encoding 0x80000002 which is not documented anywhere. Since translate.google.com is returning UTF-8 result, you should write

```
NSString *contentOfResponseDataInJsonValue = 
   [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

or let the system determines the encoding for you,

```
NSString *contentOfResponseDataInJsonValue = 
   [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the Unicode table, and indeed

- `\U515c` is 兜  ,
- `\U639b` is 掛  ,
- `\U8e55` is 蹕  .

The combination of those three letters doesn't make sense to me (as a Japanese), but that's what you have in JSON data.

What do you want to do? In order to be helped, you need to explain about what you want to be helped.

Comment: oh,sorry!
NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://translate.google.cn/translate_a/t?client=t&text=%@&hl=zh-CN&sl=%@&tl=%@&multires=1&otf=2&pc=0&sc=1",strTextOfFilter,@"en", @"zh-CN" ];

NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL];

NSString *contentOfResponseDataInJsonValue=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:encoder=-2147483646 error:&error]; NSLog(@"%@",url);
 why i copy url in browser。return result is [[["奥本罗","AABENRAA","Ào běn luō"]],,"en"].
 but NSLog(@"%@",contentOfResponseDataInJsonValue); print [[["兜掛蹕","AABENRAA"," o b豆n lu身"]],,"en"].

Comment: I still don't understand. Please explain what you want to achieve. Posting "this code does A, that code does B" doesn't tell us what you want to do.